# Javascript switch statement calculation called by another function to display result calculation

Tags: javascript

I need to display a calculation made on switch statement.

The application should have two functions: one to calculate the ranking and one to display the ranking using switch statement to determine the raking as a parameter. it should have the "Senior Master" in the console.

The ranking system is as follows.

```
Ranking
Rating Points
Senior master
2400 +
National master
2200–2399
Expert
2000–2199
Class A
1800–1999
Class B
1600–1799
```

The display function should call the calculate function, passing the player ranking points as an argument to that function.

Example output of the application:

Senior Master

I tried using only the switch statement getting the result of the supposed calculation. I am still very confused as I am supposed to display the calculation in a second function.

I am having a result that does not seems correct.

here's the my code.

```
(function (seniorMaster) { // Self executing function. Protects global space. 

    function calculateRanking() {

        seniorMaster = "2400 + ";

        switch (seniorMaster) {

            case ("2400 + "):

                ("Senior Master");

                break;

            case ("2200 - 2399"):

                console.log("National Master");

                break;

            case ("2000 - 2199"):

                console.log("Expert");

                break;

            case ("1800 - 1999"):

                console.log("Class A");

                break;

            case ("1600 - 1799"):

                console.log("Class B");
        }
    }

    calculateRanking(); // need another function to display the raking

})();

function display(){ // not sure if the second function is correct

    console.log("Senior Master")

}display()
```

Comment: `("Senior Master")` should be `console.log("Senior Master")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use a switch statement to print the result, but if you really need to, I would create two functions, like so:

```
function getRank(strRank) {
  const rank = parseInt(strRank);
    if (rank >= 2400) return "Senior Master";
    if (rank >= 2200 && rank <= 2399) return "National Master";
    if (rank >= 2000 && rank <= 2199) return "Expert";
    if (rank >= 1800 && rank <= 1999) return "Class A";
    if (rank >= 1600 && rank <= 1799) return "Class B";
    else return "No rank";
} 

function printRank(rank) {
  switch (rank) {
    case "Senior Master":
    case "National Master":
    case "Expert":
    case "Class A":
    case "Class B":
      console.log(rank);
      break;
    default:
      console.log("No matching rank");
      break;
  }
}

printRank(getRank("2400")); // => "Senior Master"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

1. You are not using `console.log` with senior-master case

   ```
   case ("2400 + "):
     ("Senior Master"); // no console.log here.
     break;
   ```
2. You cannot use `calculateRanking();` inside `display()` because `calculateRanking()` is outside the scope of `display()`
3. You want to pass ranking inside `calculateRanking()` then first make it something like `calculateRanking(seniorMaster)` that will help you to pass rank/score parameter in `calculateRanking(seniorMaster)`
4. put display() inside the self executing function to allow it access `calculateRanking` function.
5. finally the code should be like

   ```
   (function (/*seniorMaster*/) { // you can remove the seniorMaster
   // parameter if it is not intended to use once. 

   function calculateRanking(seniorMaster) { //pass argument with it so 
   //that it could perform action according to input
       switch (seniorMaster) {

           //  if you don't want to use string comparsion but interested
          // to use numeric comparison then use
           case ("2400 + "): //  case (seniorMaster >= 2400):

               console.log("Senior Master");

               break;

           case ("2200 - 2399"):

               //  case (seniorMaster >= 2200 && seniorMaster < 2400):

               console.log("National Master");

               break;

           case ("2000 - 2199"): //  case (seniorMaster >= 2000 && seniorMaster < 2200):

               console.log("Expert");

               break;

           case ("1800 - 1999"): //  case (seniorMaster >= 1800 && seniorMaster < 2000):

               console.log("Class A");

               break;

           case ("1600 - 1799"): //  case (seniorMaster >= 1600 && seniorMaster < 1800):

               console.log("Class B");
       }
   }

   //calculateRanking(seniorMaster); --- You should be more specific to use it here as 
   // I don't think it would be useful to call it here if you want to
   // use display() to display ranking otherwise you are free to use it.

   //You don't require display() but still if there is 
   //some specific purpose of it you may use it

   function display(){
       //call the function here
       //here you
       var seniorMaster = "2400 + "; //  if you want to go with numeric comparison use --- 
       //var seniorMaster = Number_Value; (where Number_Value is any +Integer)
       calculateRanking(seniorMaster);
   }

   display();
   })();
   ```